# Перенаправить логи в JavaFX TextArea

Tags: java, javafx, логирование, slf4j, logback

Есть десктопное приложение, написанное на JavaFX (UI) и Spring Boot. Связка выполнена с помощью FxWeaver. Нужно сделать следующее: на форме есть TextArea, предназначенная для вывода логов. Хотелось бы не писать свой логгер, а перенаправить вывод @Slf4j (logback) на форму.
Написал свой appender, но проблема в том, что его нужно инициализировать в каждом классе отдельно (т. е. нужно постоянно получать ссылку на объект TextArea из главного контроллера), что крайне неудобно. Инициализация в методе initialize в контроллере (см. код ниже) позволяет перенаправить вывод slf4j только в текущем классе. Есть ли способ перенаправить вывод один раз и глобально, для всего проекта?

**StaticOutputStreamAppender.java**

```
public class StaticOutputStreamAppender<E> extends OutputStreamAppender<E> {
private static final DelegatingOutputStream DELEGATING_OUTPUT_STREAM = new DelegatingOutputStream(null);

@Override
public void start() {
    setOutputStream(DELEGATING_OUTPUT_STREAM);
    super.start();
}

public static void setStaticOutputStream(OutputStream outputStream) {
    DELEGATING_OUTPUT_STREAM.setOutputStream(outputStream);
}

private static class DelegatingOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {
    public DelegatingOutputStream(OutputStream out){
        super(new OutputStream() {
            @Override
            public void write(int b) {}
        });
    }

    void setOutputStream(OutputStream outputStream) {
        this.out = outputStream;
    }
}
```

}

**TextAreaLogger.java**

```
public class TextAreaLogger extends OutputStream {
    private final TextArea textArea;

    public TextAreaLogger(TextArea textArea) {
        this.textArea = textArea;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> textArea.appendText(String.valueOf((char) b)));
    }
}
```

**Метод initialize в контроллере:**

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    StaticOutputStreamAppender.setStaticOutputStream(new TextAreaLogger(loggingTextArea));*/
}
```

**logback.xml**

```
<appender name="textAreaAppender" class="yevhenii.screenshooter.logging.StaticOutputStreamAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{70}: %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="textAreaAppender" />
    </root>
```

Comment: Посмотрите на ответ тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247784/redirecting-slf4j-log-to-textarea-in-javafx

Comment: Да, я по этому примеру и делал. Ошибка у меня оказалась в том, что логика выполняется в том же потоке, что и обновляется UI, и следовательно, я не увижу в TextArea новых логов, пока не закончится работа сервиса, в котором выводятся сами логи. Верно я предполагаю?

Comment: Ах как. Обычно все обновления ui держат отдельно в потоке чтоб не подвисал ui.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, вопрос закрыт.